# How can I use an image from my body content for Facebook OG:image tag?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to figure out how pages on my site can use images from the body content when shared on Facebook. As far as I can tell these images can only be set with the meta tag og:image inside the head tag (which makes no sense to me since images shouldn't be there) but I have no good way of taking an image from the body and inserting into the head. I don't think using JS would work because FB's scraper would have to run JS too and even if it did work it seems like a poor solution. I could also write some PHP to get the page content and parse it checking for img tags and then return the output to my template in the head tag but this again seems like a poor solution.

Further, I don't understand why other websites don't seem to have this issue. For instance, this site has no OG tags at all but if you try to share the page on Facebook it nicely places the body image in the post: http://www.eng.lsu.edu/news/2015/1/more-than-an-alumna/

But my site won't show any images at all, with or without the OG tags unless I explicitly set one with og:image. https://www.tntech.edu/engineering/news-events/news/2014-2015-coe-news/sae-india-trip-return

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: _“but I have no good way of taking an image from the body and inserting into the head”_ – well then find one. If the system you are using to manage your site is too inflexible to achieve that … well, that’s basically your problem, not Facebook’s.

Comment: As to “why other websites don’t have this issue” – if no OG meta information is present, then Facebook tries to determine what parts of the page content and what images _might_ be relevant. Depending on HTML structure amongst other factors they might to a better job of that for some pages than for others. Anyway, the way for you to _specify_ which image you want to be used exists – so either implement it, or live with things maybe not working out in your favor automatically.

Comment: _"well then find one"_ - Why do you think I'm here? Do YOU think JS or extra PHP is a good solution?

Comment: I don’t know _anything_ about the system you are using, so how do you suppose I could possibly answer that?

Comment: What does the system matter? JS is JS and PHP is PHP. Using JS means that the client has to do extra work on every page and if Facebook's scraper doesn't execute JS then it's a non-starter. Using PHP means the server has to do extra work on every page but it can be cached and there's no need for extra work client-side. The ideal solution would be HTML/CSS but it seems like this doesn't exist.

Comment: You said you had _“no good way of taking an image from the body and inserting into the head”_ – and therefor I’m wondering what kind of system (read as: CMS, if you like) you are using, that doesn’t allow you to access _data_ (here: body content) before it creates _output_ (here: the `head` section of the document).

Comment: Of course the system I'm using allows me to access the data but as I said I'm not sure parsing the body content a second time is really the best thing to do. I was hoping there might be a way to accomplish this via markup changes that wouldn't put any extra load on the server or client but if that's not possible then certainly I have other options at my disposal. I'm looking for input on the best way to do this. I feel like you've been hostile toward me and I don't know why.

Comment: @Dave it's because he works for facebook :D

Comment: @Simone are all people who work for Facebook dicks or just this guy? lol